# com.huawei.agconnect plugin not found

Tags: android, gradle, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery-connect

So I'm trying to add AppGallery connect gradle plugin to my android project using new Kotlin DSL syntax. But I'm getting error like this:

```
org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Build file 'D:\#KERJAAN\devbase\sample\build.gradle.kts' line: 3
Plugin [id: 'com.huawei.agconnect', version: '1.6.3.300'] was not found in any of the following sources:
- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.huawei.agconnect:com.huawei.agconnect.gradle.plugin:1.6.3.300')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
    Google
    MavenRepo
    maven(https://developer.huawei.com/repo/)
```

What i did was adding repository for plugin like this in `settings.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { setUrl("https://developer.huawei.com/repo/") }
    }
}
```

And adding the plugin like this in app's `build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
plugins {
   id("com.huawei.agconnect") version "1.6.3.300"
}
```

Interestingly, It works if using classpath from the root `build.gradle.kts`. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Any Gradle plugin (this is not AGC specific at all) can only be loaded at the root project level, and then usually be applied on the module level. I've just tried to remove the `buildscript` block (alike in the question), which indeed leads to:

```
Plugin [id: 'com.huawei.agconnect', version: '1.7.3.302', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:
maven(https://developer.huawei.com/repo/)

Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.huawei.agconnect:com.huawei.agconnect.gradle.plugin:1.7.3.302')
```

The plugin dependency won't resolve, while the `pluginManagement` keeps adding `.gradle.plugin`. If the repository would know about the full and not  only the shorthanded name `agcp`, this should work out of the box (that's actually the default expected package name, unless changing it):

```
com.huawei.agconnect:com.huawei.agconnect.gradle.plugin:1.7.3.302
```

And this doesn't match:

```
com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.7.3.302
```

---

One can use `pluginManagement.resolutionStrategy` as a temporary workaround ...

The `settings.gradle` is being used to rewrite the wrongfully assumed package name:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/' }
    }
    plugins {}
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachPlugin {
            if (it.requested.id.getNamespace() == 'com.huawei.agconnect') {
                println ">> ${it.requested.id.id}"
                if (it.requested.id.id == 'com.huawei.agconnect.agcp') {
                    it.useModule('com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.7.3.302')
                }
                if (it.requested.id.id == 'com.huawei.agconnect.apms') {
                    it.useModule('com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-apms-plugin:1.6.1.300')
                }
                println ">> ${it.target}"
            } else {
                println ">  ${it.target}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`plugins` have to be defined in `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.1" apply false
    id "com.android.library" version "7.3.1" apply false
    id "com.huawei.agconnect.agcp" version "1.7.3.302" apply false
    id "com.huawei.agconnect.apms" version "1.6.1.300" apply false
}
```

`println` will output the updated (fake) `id` to `artifact` mapping `it.target`:

```
[
    id: 'com.huawei.agconnect.agcp',
    version: '1.7.3.302',
    artifact: 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.7.3.302',
    apply: false
]
```

When applying it, one still needs to use the real `id`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.huawei.agconnect'
```

---

It is just that (as of version 1.7.3.302) `APMSTransform` has some check in place, which requires to explicitly put AGP on `classpath`. The `buildscript` block is "almost" obsolete, if not `APMSTransform` would wrongfully assume, that it is the only place where the Android Gradle plugin can be loaded.

```
/** Still required due to AGCP plugin. */
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
    }
}
```

It would also need to check for either of these plugins:

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.1" apply false
    id "com.android.library" version "7.3.1" apply false
}
```

For example:

```
project.getPluginManager().hasPlugin('com.android.application') || project.getPluginManager().hasPlugin('com.android.library')
```

---

In order to make this work flawlessly (without `resolutionStrategy`), this would require an updated check, in order not to get `com.android.tools.build:gradle` is no set in the `build.gradle` file and
also an URL rewrite, which would handle the package name's `.gradle.plugin` suffix properly, so that `com.huawei.agconnect.gradle.plugin` and `agcp` would result in the same package download. `resolutionStrategy` indeed is the workaround and not the answer.

Comment: This is what i've been looking for

Comment: @JimlyAsshiddiqy Updated the answer; now explicitly checking for `it.requested.id.id`.

Comment: where they are going to fix? is there any new name of Huawei plugin for Gradle KTS?

Comment: Thank you, that you shared your knoweledge - it was really helpful for me!

Answer (score 3):

Huawei has released version 1.9.1.300 of their SDK/plugin, which now fortunately supports Gradle 8.0

```
1.9.1.300
2023-07-04
Modified the SDK to make it compatible with Android Gradle 8.0.
```

Here's a [link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-appmessage-sdkchangenotes-android-0000001072373122). It still doesn't work out of the box with the current Android Studio, but at least negates the need for a resolution strategy (@Martin Zeitler thanks, your answer really helped a while back).
Here's some sample code for anyone interested:

**build.gradle *Project***

```
buildscript
{
   repositories
    {
     maven {url = uri("https://developer.huawei.com/repo/") }
    }
   dependencies
    {
      classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1')
      classpath("com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.9.1.300")
    }
}
plugins 
{
  id 'com.android.application' version '8.1.1' apply false
  id 'com.android.library' version '8.1.1' apply false
}
```

**build.gradle *:app***

```
plugins 
{
  id 'com.android.application'
  id 'com.huawei.agconnect'
}
android
{
 ...
}
dependencies 
{
  implementation 'com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-core:1.9.1.300'
}
```

**settings.gradle *Project***

```
pluginManagement {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/' }
    gradlePluginPortal()
 }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/' }
 }
}
rootProject.name = "SomeProject"
include ':app'
```

Comment: best completed answer to implementation with gradle 8+

Answer (score 1):

Don't use

```
plugins {
   id("com.huawei.agconnect") version "1.6.3.300"
}
```

PLS old way like use

```
dependencies {
    // 增加agcp插件配置，推荐您使用最新版本的agcp插件。
    classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.6.3.300'
    // important add next line , huawei dependencies agp.
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could not resolve com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.6.1.300

if you have this error while building apk or bundle
then change the path
from

```
com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.6.1.300
```

to

```
com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.6.5.300
```

it works for me

Comment: you can not use such thing with Gradle KTS

Answer (score 0):

The correct (easiest and official) solution is like @SurePing already mentioned. It is not the "old way", it is the recommended way  [in the Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:applying_plugins_buildscript)

The agcp plugin needs the com.android.tools.build.gradle, add this to the top level build.gradle.kts file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {url = uri("https://developer.huawei.com/repo/") }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.0")
        classpath("com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.9.0.300")
    }
}
```