# How to update latest gradle version of kotlin library

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin-multiplatform

I created a library in multiplatform in  latest intellij. My intellj added the outdated gradle version
**settings.gradle.kts**

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachPlugin {
            if (requested.id.namespace == "com.android") {
                useModule("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2"). // How to update to latest version and what is the use of 4.1.2?
            }
        }
    }
}
rootProject.name = "xyz"
```

I commented above in my code. Can someone guide **how can I update my gradle version to latest and what is the use of 4.1.2** that piece of code?

I tried to remove 4.1.2 below piece of code then I am getting issue

```
 resolutionStrategy {
     eachPlugin {
         if (requested.id.namespace == "com.android") {
             useModule("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2")
         }
     }
 }
```

**Error**

```
 Build file '/Users/vmodi/IdeaProjects/abc/build.gradle.kts' line: 1
 
 Plugin [id: 'com.android.application'] was not found in any of the following sources:
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
 distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
 distributionPath=wrapper/dists
 distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip
 zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
 zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

**build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.6.21"
    id("com.android.application")
}

group = "com.abc"
version = "0.0.1"

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

kotlin {
    android()
    iosX64()
    iosArm64()
    iosSimulatorArm64()

    sourceSets {
        val ktorVersion = "2.0.0"
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-auth:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core:1.3.2")
                implementation("io.insert-koin:koin-core:3.2.0-beta-1")
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-okhttp:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging-jvm:$ktorVersion")
            }
            val iosX64Main by getting
            val iosArm64Main by getting
            val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
            val iosMain by creating {
                dependsOn(commonMain)
                iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
                iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
                iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
                dependencies {
                    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:$ktorVersion")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdk = 21
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.abc.kotlinmultiplatform"
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 31
    }
    @Suppress("UnstableApiUsage")
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

**IntelliJ version**

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.1 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-221.5591.52, built on May 10, 2022
Licensed to Vivek Modi
For educational use only.
Runtime version: 11.0.14.1+1-b2043.45 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 11.6.5
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 16
Non-Bundled Plugins:
    com.intellij.nativeDebug (221.5591.54)
    org.jetbrains.kotlin-js-inspection-pack-plugin (0.0.9)

Kotlin: 221-1.6.21-release-337-IJ5591.52
```

After @PylypDukhov suggestion, trying to update **gradle** `7.0.4` I am getting this weird error

**error**

```
Failed to query the value of property 'namespace'.
Package Name not found in /Users/vmodi/IdeaProjects/abc/src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml, and namespace not specified. Please specify a namespace for the generated R and BuildConfig classes via android.namespace in the module's build.gradle file like so:

android {
    namespace 'com.example.namespace'
}
```

**settings.gradle.kts**

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachPlugin {
            if (requested.id.namespace == "com.android") {
                useModule("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4")
            }
        }
    }
}
rootProject.name = "LetsGetCheckedKotlinMultiplatform"
```

Added **androidMain**

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.abc"/>
```

Comment: Why you even need a `resolutionStrategy`? For comparison, this would be a valid use-case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71135974/549372 ...just apply the plugin in the module where you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**4.1.2** is android gradle plugin version, it's not related to gradle version.

Android gradle plugin is shipped with **Android Studio**, if you wanna use latest version mentioned by @Egor, you have to use **Android Studio**.

**IntelliJ IDEA** supports them with a delay - the last supported version at the moment is **7.0.4**, which works fine to me, the only problem you might have with it is the lack of support for the **32** target version of Android - but it's not required to upload the app and will work fine on 32 devices, also you can build release version in **AS** with newest plugin, and develop in **IDEA**, as to me it seems more performant in KMM projects.

Comment: thanks for great advice. I tried to update my **gradle** to `7.0.4` but it giving me error. I added my error in my question. Please have a look and guide me. Thanks

Comment: @vivekmodi have you tried opening `/Users/vmodi/IdeaProjects/abc/src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml`? Each android module should contain a valid manifest file.

Comment: I added `package`in my manifest and update to gradle `7.0.4` is working fine now. Thank you so much. One question can we check which android gradle is release from intellij. Any document/site bcoz I cannot find any doc. Do you know about that?

Comment: @vivekmodi I wasn’t being able to find out, let me know if you reach such info:)

Comment: I found this web [page](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-287437)

Answer (score 0):

4.1.2 is the version number. To find out what the latest version is, visit [Google's Maven Repository](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=com.android.tools.build#com.android.tools.build:gradle). At the time of writing, the latest stable version is 7.2.0, so simply replace "4.1.2" with "7.2.0" and rebuild the project.